# Authentication works locally but fail after deploying to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, cookies, token

I deployed a Nodejs backend to AWS EC2, and front-end React app was deployed to AWS S3. The build version worked on my local machine. But after deployment, when I logged in the app, the token was received from the backend, but then I got 401 unauthenticated error, and the app will then logout as I coded.
I took a screenshot of the error was happening.
[image: The token was received in cookies, but I got 401 error]

In my backend code, login controller is like this:

```js
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).exec();
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send('No user found');

        const match = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
        if (!match) return res.status(400).send('Wrong password');

        const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: '7d',
        });
        user.password = undefined;
        res.cookie('token', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'None',
        });
        res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send('Error. Try again.');
    }
};
```

and all the requests go through a jwt middleware:

```js
const { expressjwt } = require('express-jwt');

const requireSignin = expressjwt({
    getToken: (req) => req.cookies.token,
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
});

module.exports = { requireSignin };
```

I have been struggling with this for weeks but didn't figure out why.

Comment: Besides, I have read about the deployment issue that can happen when react app deployed on AWS S3, I tried to set the error page and cloudfront to solve the 403 and 404 error to redirect to index.html. However, in this app, I still got 404 error in my console. Which is another issue that confuses me.